# WordPress: moved wordpress dashboard still pointing to testing server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I uploaded my wordpress  site to my testing server something like this: 201.99.1.11/mysite  for testing purpose and then downloaded complete root folder in my system , exported database and then uploaded it to my live server did setup database and in wp-config.php did setup username , password and db name also , Front-end of the site  is working perfectly but when i try to login to dashboard it redirects me back to testing server .  where should i make change to make sure i get logged in to my live version of the site instead i am redirected to testing version

Comment: Did you update the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` option values?

Comment: no i  did not  know about that. for dashboard  what should i set ? if my site is mysite.com

Comment: You need to change url of your site from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options - you can either edit the `options` table for WordPress, or you can set the `WP_HOME` and `SITE_URL` constants in your `wp-config.php`. I would recommend the latter as it is a test site, and you may move it back and forth.

To edit the options table, use a SQL query analyzer from your desktop, or if available something like *phpMyAdmin*. You will need to find the entries for `siteurl` and `home` in this table, and set the values to your localhost.

If you wish to use `wp-config.php` just edit the file and add the following lines:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://YOUR_HOSTNAME/' );
define( 'SITE_URL', 'http://YOUR_HOSTNAME/' );
```

Where "YOUR_HOSTNAME" is the hostname of your local machine (or just localhost) + path if you are still using one.

You can find more info on the WordPress site on [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Comment: i added these lines in function.php  at the top is that correct update_option('siteurl','mysite.com/');
  update_option('home','mysite.com/');

Comment: They need to be added to `wp-config.php`, not `functions.php` - the former loads first but your functions are called once your theme is loaded.

Comment: And make sure to change "YOUR_HOSTNAME" to whatever the URL of your local WordPress install is... `http://localhost/mysite/` for example.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment... the `update_option()` calls should set the values of those options to "mysite.com" however you need to include the protocol (http or https). If this site is running locally then you need to use a local hostname like "localhost" and not the public domain.

Comment: after  define('DB_COLLATE', ''); i added  define('WP_HOME','example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','example.com'); so where  do i update localhost options

Comment: yes i added that but stackoverflow does not allow that in comments

Comment: Got it... just wanted to confirm. You should be able to either use the `update_option()` method (once you load the site once it should reset the DB values and you can delete it) or you can set the constants in `wp-config.php` (the need to remain) or you can update the database manually (only needs to be done once). I thought you were moving the site to your local computer (which is why I said localhost) but if it is on the internet, use the correct domain name for it.

Comment: thank you very much  @doublesharp . u  really saved me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Open your database from your hosting panel. Edit the wp-options table and change the "siteurl" and "home" column value to your live server url

Comment: what should be url of dashboard ?

Comment: You just need to put your site url. For example, if your website domain name is http://example.com , you should put http://example.com into "siteurl" and "home" column value

Comment: @AdiNugroho If the site is running locally, there is no "hosting panel".

Comment: @AdiNugroho Assuming you have phpMyAdmin running locally. I don't.